# How to reorganize one column data to multi-column data

Tags: r

I have a dataset read from xls looks like this:

```
x<-c("c1", 1, 2, 3, "c2", 2, 6, 8, "c3", 4, 3, 2)
x<-as.data.frame(x)
```

How can I reorganize it to this format in R:

```
c1 c2 c3
1 2 4
2 6 3
3 8 2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
m <- matrix(c('c1','1','2','3','c2','2','6','8','c3','4','3','2'), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)  
df <- setNames(data.frame(m[-1,]),m[1,])

> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  1  2  4
2  2  6  3
3  3  8  2
```